# Laravel - errno: 150 Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to to make a relation between company model and jobs model
But it gives me this error:

```
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `my-career`.`#sql-2fd8_ba` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")
```

Company Model:

```
class Company extends Model{
    public $table="comppanies";
    public function jobs() {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Job::class);
    }
}
```

Job Model:

```
class Job extends Model{
    public $table="jobs";
    public function company() {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Company::class, 'company_id');
    }
}
```

Job Table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
    });
}
```

I don't know where is the problem

Comment: show us your migration order

Comment: i am new to laravel

Comment: you have a migration folder in your project,,make a screenshot and share here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use table name `comppanies` in the reference source, so :

```
$table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
```

Should be :

```
$table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('comppanies');
_____________________________________________________^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: i got the same problem

Comment: Have you rolled back the table and remigrating it with the correct reference?

Comment: yes i removed all tables from table and i did migrate again

Comment: The error show _Can't create table `my-career`_ is there another table that you forgot to reference it in the question called `my-career`?

Comment: Ok good, could you please show us the `companies` migration that should be migrated first before `jobs`.

Comment: ohh i have jobs before companies

Comment: (Y) Good job you found the problem then :)